# How to get count of records month-wise from mysql table?

Tags: mysql, count

I have a mysql table points like this

```
id | points | orderid | date
1  | 10     | 1234    | 2014-01-14
2  | 20     | 4321    | 2014-02-04
3  | 10     | 1234    | 2014-01-13
```

I want to get count of records for unique orderids

like if i want to fech total records for month of jan then result will be

**1** not 2 because i need to fetch records for unique orderids

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the `DISTINCT` modifier in the `COUNT()` function.

```
SELECT YEAR(date) AS y, MONTH(date) AS m, COUNT(DISTINCT orderid)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY y, m
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(date_reg) M, YEAR(date_reg) Y, COUNT(MONTHNAME(date_reg)) T 
FROM users 
WHERE date_reg BETWEEN DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(NOW()), INTERVAL 
   DAY(LAST_DAY(NOW())) DAY), INTERVAL 5 MONTH), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND   
   DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(NOW()), INTERVAL DAY(LAST_DAY(NOW())) DAY) 
GROUP BY M 
ORDER BY Y, M DESC;
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to stackoverflow. Fo the future, please have a look at how you can properly format the code in your answers (http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Also, giving a bit of context to the answer and not just the code could help other readers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substr` function of MySQL to cut down the complete date string into year and month and group the resulting string.

```
select substr(createdTime,1,7) as month,COUNT(1) from TABLENAME where {CONDITION} group by month order by 1;
```